# minimize, maximize, close; wifi, sound etc. title bars size increasing

Tags: icons, fonts, resize, scaling, maximized

guys I am pretty new to ubuntu, just installed 17.10 version, been playing around for a while and I was wondering is there any chance I could increase at least MIN, MAXI and CLOSE button size, its way too small to be clicked/aimed fast and efficiently, thanks. :)

p.s. I googled for a solution, found this: "Go to System Settings > Displays > Scale for menu and title bars" it didnt seem to work, couldnt find scale for menu and title bars option in displays.

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to Ubuntu!

Ubuntu uses Gnome by default (I'm assuming you already know what a desktop environment is). Unfortunately, if you like customization Gnome may not be your cup of tea, that's because it focuses more on usability and stability rather than configurability. As far as I know, there is no way to change that other than modifying the code. *However*, Gnome does support shell themes, and even though these will change a lot more than just the size of those buttons, you could find a shell theme whose buttons are larger than those you have right now.

By the way, if you like to tinker and customize your system, I'd suggest you to learn more about Kubuntu, an Ubuntu flavor running KDE Plasma (this one is very, *very*, customisable).